# load data from JSON to an object programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have data from JSON response that I am transferring to an array as shown below

```
            originalPerson.firstname  = [memberData valueForKey:@"firstname"];
            originalPerson.lastname   = [memberData valueForKey:@"lastname"];                              
            originalPerson.address1   = [memberData valueForKey:@"address1"];
```

Is there a way to handle this in a loop rather than typing each line out? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the class of the instance originalPerson is key-value coding (KVC) compliant, you could use something like

```
for (NSString* key in [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"firstname", @"lastname", @"address1", nil]) {
    [originalPerson setValue:[memberData valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
}
```

or even

```
for (NSString* key in [memberData allKeys]) {
    [originalPerson setValue:[memberData valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
}
```

if member data is a dictionary and you're sure (or check that) originalPerson has the corresponding properties. I don't know how you are parsing your JSON but I recomend [SBJSON](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) for objective C.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. OBj-C is great!! I'm using SBJson but just found out that it is no longer supported. So at some point I'll probably switch.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
[originalPerson setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:memberData]
```

be careful that `memberData` should not contain any key that does not correspond to an attribute of `originalPerson`, or the runtime will raise an exception.